# Debian Nagios NRPE connection refused

Tags: debian, monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I have already checked some docs from here, but still coundt find the solution.
I have a nagios server and a webserver to be monitored (RAM). Debian both
Server and plugins are installed correctly. Port 5666 is open in both.
As we can see below the webserver is allowing connections from 192.168.0.119 as I configured to allow it.
Output of nrpe.cfg log

`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 systemd[1]: Started Nagios Remote Plugin Executor.`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: parse_allowed_hosts: parsing the allowed host string >192.168.0.119< to add to ACL list`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: parse_allowed_hosts: ADDING this record (192.168.0.119) to ACL list!`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: add_ipv4_to_acl: checking ip-address >192.168.0.119<`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: add_ipv4_to_acl: ip-address >192.168.0.119< correct, adding.`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: parse_allowed_hosts: Record added to ACL list!`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: Showing ACL lists for both IP and DOMAIN acl's:`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]:    IP ACL: 192.168.0.119/32 1996531904`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: Added command[check_mem]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem  -f -w 20 -c 10`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: INFO: SSL/TLS initialized. All network traffic will be encrypted.`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: Starting up daemon`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: SETUP_WAIT_CONN FOR: IPv4 address: 127.0.0.1 ((null))`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: Server listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5666.`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: Listening for connections on port 5666`
`Apr 12 13:34:14 webserver2 nrpe[903]: Allowing connections from: 192.168.0.119`

but when I run below from nagios I got connection refused error.

`nagios@nagios:/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.0.166 –c check_mem`
`connect to address 192.168.0.166 port 5666: Connection refused`
`connect to host 192.168.0.166 port 5666: Connection refused`

of course running locally from webserver (192.168.0.166) works fine
`root@webserver2:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ./check_mem -f -w 20 -c 10`
`OK - 91.5% (1870592 kB) free.|TOTAL=2043252KB;;;; USED=172660KB;1634601;1838926;; FREE=1870592KB;;;; CACHES=83440KB;;;;`

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share output of `netstat -natup| grep 5666` command from webserver and `telnet 192.168.0.166 5666` from Nagios server?

Comment: Thanks Rohlik. It is working now. I just did a couple of services restart and after a few min started to work :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!